# Multicolored divs

Tags: php, css

my site which is a search engine returns many many results with a foreach loop as such:

```
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $result) {
    $ltitle = $result->title;
    $ldesc = $result->description;
    $url = $result->displayUrl;
    $link = $result->link;

    if (strlen($ltitle) > 60)
    {
$title = substr($ltitle,0,60).'...' ;
    }
    else
    {
    $title = $ltitle;
    }

if (strlen($ldesc) > 195)
    {
$desc = substr($ldesc,0,195).'...' ;
    }
    else
    {
    $desc = $ldesc;
    }


    echo "

<br>


<div class='resultbox'>

<a class='normal' style='text-decoration:none;font-size:huge;font-weight:bold' href='$link'>$title</a><br>
<div style='padding-top:3px;padding-bottom:4px;width:580px;'>
<font style='text-decoration:none;font-size:small;font-family:Arial;'>$desc<br></font></div>
<a style='text-decoration:none;' href='$link'><font style='text-decoration:none;font-size:small;color:green;font-weight:bold;'>$url<br></font></a>

</div>
";
}
```

And the resultbox class above styles all of the results with this

```
.resultbox
{
height:auto;
width:600px;
background-color:transparent;
font-size:19px;
padding:10px;
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
border-left: 6px solid #333;
}
.resultbox:hover
{
border-left: 8px solid #555;
}
```

The border-left color is what i want changed, i would like it to generate or to style randomly off of a list of colour codes so the results, insead of being all #333 can be #333 #555 #999 and so on..... any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: don't know where to start

Comment: google won because it's simple.

Comment: Do you mind using JS?

Comment: @Connor Check my solution. Gives you infinite options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `<div class='resultbox'>` to `<div class='resultbox random-color-".rand(1,YOUR_COLOR_LIMIT)."'>` AND define colors like

```
.random-color-1 {
     border-left: 8px solid #555;
}
.random-color-2 {
     border-left: 8px solid #555;
}
.....
.random-color-YOUR_COLOR_LIMIT {
     border-left: 8px solid #555;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If u have no problems using JS , You can certainly do this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.resultbox').mouseenter(function() {
        var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
     $('.resultbox').css("border-left", " 8px solid #"+randomColor);    
    });
});
```

Comment: is this jquery, what do I include?

Comment: You just need to include //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 1):

change

`<div class='resultbox'>`

to

`<div class='resultbox' style='border-left-color:$yourColorInCssFormat;'>`

the style attribute overrides the css from class.
set `$yourColorInCssFormat` to the color you wish to have for the div. for example: `$yourColorInCssFormat = '#999';`

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline style for that. Or alternatively you can user **nth-child** selector of css to repeat the border-color scheme something like this:

```
.resultbox:nth-child(n+1):hover {

}

.resultbox:nth-child(2n+1):hover {

}

.resultbox:nth-child(3n+1):hover {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, try this out for your foreachloop:

```
<?php foreach ($xml->channel->item as $result): ?>
    <?php 
       $ltitle = $result->title;
       $ldesc = $result->description;
       $url = $result->displayUrl;
       $link = $result->link;

       if (strlen($ltitle) > 60){
           $title = substr($ltitle,0,60).'...' ;
       }else{$title = $ltitle;}

       if (strlen($ldesc) > 195){
           $desc = substr($ldesc,0,195).'...' ;
       }else{$desc = $ldesc;}
    ?>



    <div class='resultbox'>

        <a class='normal' style='text-decoration:none;font-size:huge;font-weight:bold' href='<?php      echo $link ?>'><?php echo $title; ?></a>
    <br>
    <div style='padding-top:3px;padding-bottom:4px;width:580px;'>
    <font style='text-decoration:none;font-size:small;font-family:Arial;'>
        <?php echo $desc; ?><br>
    </font>
    </div>
        <a style='text-decoration:none;' href='<?php echo $link; ?>'><font style='text-  decoration:none;font-size:small;color:green;font-weight:bold;'><?php echo $url; ?><br></font>  </a>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

That way you're not playing with big echos.

Now for generating random colors your could use php rand();

For example:

```
//Generate a random number between the two parameters
$randomNumber = rand(1, 3);

//Use this number to dictate what the variable color should be
if($randomNumber == 1){$color = "#333"}
elseif($randomNumber == 2){$color = "#555"}
elseif($randomNumber == 3){$color = "#999"}
```

You can then use the variable $color in your code to randomly assign one of the colors to elements.

Hope this helps!

-Gui

Comment: Thats nice but i need a resultbox for each result, would that still work, and also does that make it more efficent

Comment: Yes, it will do everything thats in between the opener foreach and endforeach for every item. As for efficiency I can't say if one is more  efficient than the other, however it is much cleaner this way.

Comment: Heres a good link to check it out: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php